# how can i transform my php array to another type of array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array that i would like to modify. i think from array to dimensional array. how can i get this

Original array:

```
Array
(
    [first_database] => learners,teachers
    [second_database] => cars,boats
)
```

What I want:

```
Array
(
    [first_database] => Array
    (
        [tables]=>learners,teachers
    )   
    [second_database] => Array
    (
        [tables]=>cars,boats
    )
)
```

this is how i build my array

```
$db = new MysqliDb ('');
$array1=$db->rawQuery('select s.SCHEMA_NAME, group_concat(t.TABLE_NAME) from information_schema.SCHEMATA s left join information_schema.TABLES t on s.SCHEMA_NAME=t.TABLE_SCHEMA group by s.SCHEMA_NAME');

foreach($array1 as $newArray){
    $database_name=$newArray['SCHEMA_NAME'];
    $tbl_name=$newArray['group_concat(t.TABLE_NAME)'];
    $dev_db_n_tbl[$database_name]=$tbl_name;
    $a1Value  = explode(',',$dev_db_n_tbl[$database_name]);
    $a2Value  = explode(',',$qa_db_n_tbl[$database_name]);
    $diff[$database_name] = implode(',',array_diff($a1Value,$a2Value));
}
```

Comment: Use `$diff[$database_name]['tables'] = implode( ... );` instead of `$diff[$database_name] = implode( ... );`

Comment: it works . but how will i then foreach each database and its tables. for exmaple i have database1 with tables-me and you from server one. how will i compare with the same from server2

Comment: If with yr previous code you do something like `foreach( $diff as $val ) { do something with $val }`, now you can do `foreach( $diff as $val ) { do something with $val['tables'] }`

Answer (score 0):

Use simple `foreach` loop.

Your required array should have same keys.

You need to have array instead of simple strings for values.

And every array should have a key `tables`.

**Corrected code:**

```
<?php
$arr = array(
 'first_database' => 'learners,teachers',
 'second_database' => 'cars,boats'
);
$newArr = array();
if (! empty($arr)) {
 foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
  $newArr[$key]['tables'] = $val;
 }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($newArr);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

[See it live here](https://3v4l.org/oYgqi)